# Turn one_two to getOneTwo

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bunch of variables in the form of `one`, `two`, `three`, `four_five` and I'd like to turn them to `getOne`, `getTwo`, `getThree`, `getFourFive`...

I wrote a formula that achieves what I want for the first three ones, but I can't achieve the *CamelCase* to variables with two words (or more) separated by an underscore.

So the formula I wrote is this:

```
=CONCAT("get";UPPER(LEFT(A1;1));RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-1))
```

How can this be expanded to achieve what I need? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SUBSTITUTE` and `PROPER`:

```
="get"&SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(A1),"_","")
```

[image]

Since your version of Excel uses `;` as the list separator:

```
="get"&SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(A1);"_";"")
```

Comment: Fantastic! It's exactly what I needed!!! So simple and yet so effective! One correction though! In the `SUBSTITUTE` I had to use semicolons `;` instead of commas `,` like in every other MS Excel formula. How did it work with commas for you? I'm using Excel 2019!

Comment: In certain Excel installations (e.g. U.S. English), the `,` is the separator. Your version uses `;` as the separator, see [this](https://exceljet.net/glossary/list-separator#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20Excel%20uses%20the,may%20use%20a%20semicolon%20(%3B).&text=Note%3A%20Excel%20automatically%20translates%20the%20separator%20in%20many%20cases) perhaps.

Comment: It is most probably a Windows setting. Under additional settings of regional settings.